# JavaScript parsers for syntax checking

Tags: javascript, command-line, parser

I'm looking for good JavaScript command-line parsers which are able to check the code syntax.

Compatible with *nix systems, ideally cross-platform libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list of generic JavaScript parsers:

- [Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn)

  > A small, fast, JavaScript-based JavaScript parser.

  Install via: `npm -g install acorn`.
- [Esprima](http://esprima.org/)

  > A high performance, standard-compliant ECMAScript parser written in ECMAScript.

  Install via: `npm -g install esprima`.
- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) by Microsoft ([GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript))

  > TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that compiles to clean JavaScript output.
- [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)

  > Traceur is a JavaScript.next-to-JavaScript-of-today compiler.
- [Flow](https://flow.org/) by Facebook ([GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/flow))

  > JavaScript parser written in OCaml. Produces SpiderMonkey AST.
- [Babylon](https://babeljs.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babylon))

  > A JavaScript parser used in Babel.

Source: [JavaScript parsers speed comparison](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/test/bench/index.html).

---

Here is the speed comparison (ops/sec or type of error) for each parser/input combination.

[image: JavaScript parsers speed comparison]

---

Related: [How can I check JavaScript code for syntax errors ONLY from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856097/55075)